# Java screensaver loading the wrong main class, any ideas?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, windows-screensaver, javafx-gradle-plugin

I'm building a Windows screensaver using Java, JavaFX, the JavaFX Packager, the Gradle JavaFX Packager plugin, etc. I generate various executable files with this configuration:

```
jfx {
    mainClass = "tech.project.project.ConfiguratorApp"
    vendor = "Project"
    appName = "Project"
    nativeReleaseVersion = version
    secondaryLaunchers = [
            [
                    appName  : "Project Renderer",
                    mainClass: "tech.project.project.RendererApp",
                    needMenu : true
            ],
            [
                    appName  : "Project Displayer",
                    mainClass: "tech.project.project.DisplayerApp",
                    needMenu : true
            ],
            [
                    appName  : "Project Screensaver",
                    mainClass: "tech.project.project.WinScreensaverApp",
                    needMenu : false
            ]
    ]
}
```

When configuring, previewing and testing the screensaver, everything works well, but when the screensaver actually runs, the main class seems to be `DisplayerApp` instead of `WinScreensaverApp`.

Any ideas why or how to gather more information about what's going on?

I managed to find the Windows command line:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\Project\PROJEC~1.SCR /s
```

Blast from the past! But I run that command manually in the console, I get the appropriate launcher called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sort of found a solution. I had various executables:

- `C:\Program Files\Project\Project A.exe`
- `C:\Program Files\Project\Project B.exe`
- `C:\Program Files\Project\Project C.exe`
- `C:\Program Files\Project\Project D.scr`

and it looked like `C:\Program Files\Project\Project A.exe` was being run instead of `C:\Program Files\Project\Project D.scr` when `C:\PROGRA~1\Project\PROJEC~1.SCR /s` was executed.

I changed the name of the screensaver to:

- `C:\Program Files\Project\ProD.scr`

and it started working correctly. I'm not exactly sure why, but since I won't investigate any further right now I wanted to post the solution in case someone else runs into a similar problem and this might shed some light on the issue.